# Rails and docker compose run tests in engine folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker-compose

I have a Rails app that runs with Docker compose.
The compose file looks like this:

```
  myapp:
    image: my-app
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
      context: my-app
      args:
        ...
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./my-app/usr/src/app
      - gem_data:/usr/local/bundle:cached
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    user: root
```

I can run tests using

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml  exec -e "RAILS_ENV=test" myapp bundle exec rspec`

Now, I have an engine inside the app:

```
 /app
    my_engine/
```

and I'd like to run the tests just for it.
How can I do it using something similar to the command above? Is there a way to target the `my_engine` folder when I run the docker-compose command, or is there another approach?

I just managed to run the test using `docker exec -it CONTAINER ID /bin/bash`, then cd in the my_engine folder and run `rspec`.

Comment: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml  exec -e "RAILS_ENV=test" myapp bundle exec rspec my_engine` should also work.  Add after rspec the path to the file/folder you want it to execute.

Comment: If I do that, it still runs the test in the main app. 
 
e.g In the engine, I define a route ```/home```. 

If I run a simple request test, it goes red because ```/home``` is not defined in the main app but just in the engine. This is solved if I mount the engine in the ```route.rb```. 
Should the engine be tested separately?